# Updating integer values with a integer variable in MS Access using Delphi 10

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, integer

```
    iexc := round(iexc/icount);
    iint := round(iint/icount);
    inau := round(inau/icount);
    iovr := round(iovr/icount);

    adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'update Tickets_Tbl set Excitment = iexc where 
    RollerCoaster = "'+sride+'"';
    adoquery1.ExecSQL;
    adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'update Tickets_Tbl set Intensity = iint where 
    RollerCoaster = "'+sride+'"';
    adoquery1.ExecSQL;
    adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'update Tickets_Tbl set Nausea = inau where 
    RollerCoaster = "'+sride+'"';
    adoquery1.ExecSQL;
    adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'update Tickets_Tbl set Overall = iovr where 
    RollerCoaster = "'+sride+'"';
    adoquery1.ExecSQL;
```

The main problem is that when I run the code it keeps saying that there is no default value for field begin updated. Please help.

Comment: Don't know Delphi, but I am guessing (based on your other lines) that `adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'update Tickets_Tbl set Excitment = iexc where` should be `adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'update Tickets_Tbl set Excitment = '+iexc+' where` (i.e. you want to insert the value from your program into the SQL statement)

Comment: The problem is that you used constant string `iexc` instead of that variable. But use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're hard-coding the variable names within your SQL instead of setting the values properly (which should be done using a parameterized query, BTW). Also, your SQL is horrific; you can do this in a single `UPDATE` instead of repeating it multiple times.

This should get you started (see note below about the `#13`):

```
iexc := round(iexc/icount);
iint := round(iint/icount);
inau := round(inau/icount);
iovr := round(iovr/icount);

AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'update Tickets_Tbl'#13 +
                      'set Excitement = :iexc,'#13 +
                      '    Intensity = :iint,'#13 +
                      '    Nausea = :inau,'#13 +
                      '    Overall = :iovr'#13 +
                      'where RollerCoaster = :sride';
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('iexc').Value := iexc;
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('iint').Value := iint;
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('inau').Value := inau;
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('iovr').Value := iovr;
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('sride').Value := sride;
AdoQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

The `#13` in the code is a carriage return, which simply makes it easier because you don't have to worry about properly inserting spaces before or after the end or start of each successive line. It's basically the same as typing the query into SQL Server Management Studio line-by-line, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of each line. You can do the same thing using `AdoQuery1.SQL.Add` for each line, but to me that makes it harder when you need to copy the SQL out and clean it up to run externally for testing or debugging or modification. The above is similar to

```
AdoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
AdoQuery1.SQL.Add('update Tickets_Tbl');
AdoQuery1.SQL.Add('set Excitement = :iexc,');
AdoQuery1.SQL.Add('Intensity = :iint,');
AdoQuery1.SQL.Add('Nausea = :inau,');
AdoQuery1.SQL.Add('Overall = :iovr');
AdoQuery1.SQL.Add('where RollerCoaster = :sride');
```

Use whichever one is easier and more readable for you personally. I use the first, because I have a utility that will take plain SQL from the clipboard and format it with the `'` and `#13 +` automatically for pasting into Delphi's Code Editor, or take that quoted text containing embedded `''` characters and `#13 +` and remove them automatically to allow pasting into SSMS or Access or another SQL utility without manual cleanup.

Comment: Why #13 and not #13#10?

Comment: @kobik: Because it doesn't seem to be necessary to use both. Using the one works fine, both in program code as shown above and when my utility converts the code back to plain text. Why type  the extra `#10` on every line when it's not needed? :-) Thanks for the edit, BTW. Good catch - I missed it when I proofread.